# derivate of a piecewise function $f(x)$ at$ x=0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

There is a piecewise function $f(x)$
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 1 ,\ \ \text{if}\ \  x \geq \ 0 \\ 0,\ \  \text{if}\ \  x<0 \end{cases}$$

what is the derivative of the $f(x)$ at $x=0$?

Is it $0$? Or since it is not continuous, the derivative does not exists?

Comment: Yes, not continuous implies not differentiable.

Comment: Note that continuity of a function at a point x does not imply that the function is differentiable at that point. Think about the absolute value function at the point x=0.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Prove that if a given function $f$ is differentiable at a point $a$, then $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Sketch: If $f$ is differentiable at $a$ then we may write (Theorem) $f(a+h) = f(a) + hf'(a) + \frac{r(h)}{h}h$ where $lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{r(h)}{h} = 0 $, then $lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h) = f(a)$, that is, $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Show that your function is not continuous at $0$. Then use the contrapositive $p \Rightarrow q \equiv\  \sim q \Rightarrow\ \sim p$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can prove that your function is not differentiable at *a*=*0* is to show that the left hand limit and the right hand limit in the definition of *f'(a)* are not equal. When you take *h* approaching *0* from the left, *f'(0)* is infinite. When you take *h* approaching *0* from the right, *f'(0)*=*0*. Since the left hand and right hand limits are not equal, *f'(0)* does not exist.

Comment: why is h from the left infinite? does x<0 mean infinite since x cannot equal 0? therefore the limit is infinite? is that the same as undefined?

Comment: No. And I'm very sorry for my formatting, for some reason my iPad doesn't want to cooperate. Ok, f'(0)=lim of h approaching 0 of f(0+h)-f(a)\h. Now look at h approaching 0 from the left, that is, along the negative x axis. What is f(0+h)=f(h) in this case? Since h<0, f(h)=0. So you will get 0-1\h=infinity, as h approaches 0.

Comment: Furthermore, as h approaches 0 from the right, h>0 and  thus f(h)=1. In this case, you get 1-1/h=0, as h approaches 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Dirac's delta function.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html

So the answer to your question is that at the origin the derivative is unlimited.
$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}{\delta(x)}=\infty$